# bitcoin compile (.undefined reference to **')

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, c++, make

I'm getting error after make command like,

**undefined reference to `BlockAssembler::BlockAssembler(CChainParams const&)'**

and in last

**Makefile:774: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed**

**make: **[all-recursive] Error 1**

I have followed all steps given here:-

https://www.toshblocks.com/bitcoin/compile-bitcoin-source-code-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

Output :-

```
 Making all in src
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin/src'
    make[2]: Entering directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin/src'
    make[3]: Entering directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin'
    make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin'
      CXXLD    bitcoind
    libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-mining.o): In function `generateBlocks(std::shared_ptr<CReserveScript>, int, unsigned long, bool)':
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:122: undefined reference to `BlockAssembler::BlockAssembler(CChainParams const&)'
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:122: undefined reference to `BlockAssembler::CreateNewBlock(CScript const&, bool)'
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:128: undefined reference to `IncrementExtraNonce(CBlock*, CBlockIndex const*, unsigned int&)'
    libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-mining.o): In function `getmininginfo(JSONRPCRequest const&)':
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:216: undefined reference to `nLastBlockWeight'
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:217: undefined reference to `nLastBlockTx'
    libbitcoin_server.a(libbitcoin_server_a-mining.o): In function `getblocktemplate(JSONRPCRequest const&)':
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:521: undefined reference to `BlockAssembler::BlockAssembler(CChainParams const&)'
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:521: undefined reference to `BlockAssembler::CreateNewBlock(CScript const&, bool)'
    /home/khushbu/bitcoin/src/rpc/mining.cpp:533: undefined reference to `UpdateTime(CBlockHeader*, Consensus::Params const&, CBlockIndex const*)'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Makefile:3888: recipe for target 'bitcoind' failed
    make[2]: *** [bitcoind] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin/src'
    Makefile:10190: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
    make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/khushbu/bitcoin/src'
    Makefile:774: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
    make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

How to solve this error and compile bitcoin source code successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're having linker errors, possibly due to the way you're installing and configuring the BerkeleyDB. It would help to post the output of the `./configure` command. Bitcoin-core recommends installing it using the Bitcoin PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev
```

Then you don't have to run `./configure` with the `LDFLAGS` and`CPPFLAGS` for BerkeleyDB.

I would recommend following the [UNIX build instructions](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.17.0/doc/build-unix.md) in the repository. First download the source code for the release you want from the [repository releases](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases).

```
$ tar xvzf v0.17.0.tar.gz && cd v0.17.0
```

Then follow the instructions in the link above.